# Amazon RDS billing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, iot, amazon-aurora

My doubt is how the Amazon RDS instance is billed. I read somewhere that it is a component based billing based on the CPU/hour, number of input/output requests, etc.,

How are the I/O requests interpreted? I have a model in which I am trying to reduce the number of input queries that go into the cloud. Will it reduce my yearly cost to a good extent?

Comment: You "read somewhere"? How about sticking with the official documentation on this subject: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/  Note how it is $0.20 per million requests. You'd have to be making billions of requests each month in order to be spending much money at all on RDS requests.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/a/386951/297130 for an explanation of an "RDS I/O request."

Answer (score 1):

Full pricing information is available on the [Amazon RDS Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/) page. It involves:

- An hourly charge for the **RDS instance**
- A charge for **data storage** based on amount of storage (including backup storage beyond the provisioned storage size)
- A **Data Transfer** for traffic flowing out of AWS to the Internet
- A minor charge for traffic flowing between Availability Zones

There are **no charges relating to database requests**. In fact, these requests are directly between client apps and the database and are not visible to AWS.

**Update:** Amazon Aurora also charges an "I/O request" charge. See comments below.

Comment: There can be I/O request charges, such as the $0.200 per 1 million requests for an Aurora database or when using magnetic storage for MySQL. I think @Pr_123 is asking what defines an "I/O request."

Comment: Ah! @jbird, you appear to be right... Aurora has the additional storage charge for "I/O requests", which would be disk access. I couldn't find a definition of that, although I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926600/how-does-amazon-rds-calculate-i-o-rate but that's not definitive.

Comment: Yeah @jbird is right ! I want to know what defines this I/O request. Say I have to query over a table of 1million data. How many I/O request would this query result in ?